# Keras image classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I trained a Keras model to classify images with 2 classes:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 150, 150, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 75, 75, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 75, 75, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 75, 75, 32)        4640      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 37, 37, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 37, 37, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling2 (None, 18, 18, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 18, 18, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 20736)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 512)               10617344  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 513       
=================================================================
Total params: 10,641,441
Trainable params: 10,641,441
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Now I want to feed a .jpg file to get a predition. I tried:

```
img_path = pathlib.Path('/content/drive/My Drive/trainingset1/images/pbs/tpb2.jpg')
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(img_path)
array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
testimg=array[:, :, 0]
```

```
testimg = (np.expand_dims(testimg,0))

print(testimg.shape)
```

```
(1, 460, 350)
```

```
probability_model = tf.keras.Sequential([model_new, tf.keras.layers.Softmax()])
predictions_single = probability_model.predict(testimg)
print(predictions_single)
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_4 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 460, 350]
```

Not sure what did I do wrong while processing the image. Did I feed the model in a wrong way?

**Updated:**

Now I can use the model without error, but no matter what image I fed, it always prints:

```
[[1.]]
```

Shouldnt it generate two values since I trained with 2 classes?

**Update2:**

Here is my code of the model:

```
model_new = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', 
           input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1)
])
```

```
model_new.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: What is the input shape of your model?

Comment: The input shape is (150, 150, 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line `testimg=array[:, :, 0]`.

Your input is missing channels.

Conv2D expects an input with shape `(batch, height, width, channel)`

Also, you may need to resize your images based on model input shape.

`img = Image.open(img_path).resize((h, w))`

Update:

Your model has many inconsistencies.

1. `dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 513` - your last layer suggests it's a binary classification problem. Use sigmoid activation in the mode, not softmax.
2. Post your full model code.

Comment: After adding `img = Image.open(img_path).resize(h, w)`, I got this error:`Unknown resampling filter (150). Use Image.NEAREST (0), Image.LANCZOS (1), Image.BILINEAR (2), Image.BICUBIC (3), Image.BOX (4) or Image.HAMMING (5)`. It seems like the Image doesnt have the resize method?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You should pass a tuple. Check the updated code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It can now make predictions, but still have some issue. I have updated my post.

Comment: I updated my post with the code of my model. How do I use sigmoid activation? Is that means I need to change the parameter of my model? Or modify this line `probability_model = tf.keras.Sequential([model_new, tf.keras.layers.Softmax()])`?

Comment: Why do you do this? `tf.keras.Sequential([model_new, tf.keras.layers.Softmax()])` Your model seems okay, but after training, just use `predict` on the main model.

Comment: When I do `predictions_single = model_new.predict(testimg)`, it returns `[[-228.16316]]`. What does this value mean? Shouldn't it be a two element array with probabilities to each class?

Comment: You should use vanilla `binary_crossentropy` and `sigmoid` at last dense layer. That will make your life easy. The output suggets it comes from a linear layer, so you need to apply sigmoid to get the actual probability.

Comment: I think I'm already using binary_crossentropy? I changed last layer as `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')`. The output is always `[[0.]]`.